# Codeigniter Loading some js while others are not loaded

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

The path seems to these files are all correct hence I expect them to be accessed. But thats not the case for some, not all. Some can be accessed but others brings a 404. 
This started after uploading my website online, but on local host it was working well.

htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

sample src that is being loaded fine:

```
<script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on page:

```
https://www.myweb.com/assets/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

sample url NOT being loaded:

```
<script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/assets/plugins/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on page:

```
 https://www.myweb.com/assets/assets/plugins/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

Comment: Check your server, file is available or not in the existing path.

Comment: it seems the file was not located on the given path

Comment: Oh, Yes Yes. Problem was not even the directory, I just realized that filenames are different, dataTables and datatables......the latter works.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized filenames were different. datatables and dataTables

```
<script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/assets/plugins/datatables/js/jquery.datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this works well.

While:

```
<script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/assets/plugins/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

failed to load.

Notice the filenames are somehow different interms of casing. `datatables.min.js` and `dataTables.min.js`

Im yet to know if filename case type can cause an error, but that solved my problem